# How can I terminate child and parent processes?

Tags: c, linux

The following code,creates a child process. This child process writes
1.000.000 random integers to a text file and then it should terminate.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

srand(time(NULL));
int list[1000000];
int number;
int evencount=0;
int oddcount=0;
int status=0;

     FILE *fp;

     if((fp= fopen("numbers.txt", "w"))==NULL){

        printf ("File cannot open!\n");

     }

pid_t child_a,child_b;
child_a=fork();

     if(child_a==0){

          printf("\nChild process ID: %d ",getpid());
          /* childA Code */
          for(int i=0; i<1000000;i++) {

                 list[i]=rand();
                 fprintf (fp,"%d ", list[i]);

          }

        kill(child_a,SIGKILL);
        printf("\nWrote 1000000 integers to numbers.txt, terminating.");

      }
```

Parent process should wait for this child process to terminate, then create an another child process. This new child process counts how many of the numbers in the text file are even and how many of them are odd and it should terminated.Also,Parent process should display process ID’s  of both child processes and terminate only after both of them are terminated.

```
else {

             child_b=fork();
             if(child_b==0){

                 /* ChildB Code */
                 printf("\nChild process ID: %d ",getpid());
                 while(list[1000000]=getw(fp)!=EOF){
                    for(int j=0;j<1000000;j++){
                      if(list[j]%2==0)
                          evencount++;
                      else
                          oddcount++;
                    }
                 }
                 printf("\nEven Numbers: %d",evencount);
                 printf("\nOdd Numbers: %d",oddcount);

                 kill(child_b,SIGKILL);
                 printf("Terminating..");

              }else{

                   /* Parent Code */
                   int parent;
                   parent=getppid();
                   child_a=wait(&status);
                   printf("\nChild process ID: %d ",child_a);
                   child_b=wait(&status);
                   printf("\nChild process ID: %d\n",child_b);

                   kill(parent,SIGKILL);
                }


           }





}
```

When I executed this code,output gives me 'killed'.So what is the problem in this code about terminating to processing?

Comment: Hint 1: you should be able to do this entire task without ever calling `kill`.

Comment: Hint 2: `kill(0, signal)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: But,how can I understand which process is killed parent or child?Do not I have to specify which process to killed?

Comment: Let me be more explicit: You don't need to kill any processes. None. You only need to have each process exit normally when its work is complete.

Comment: I tried kill(0,signal) . But I took an error:                                                              expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘void (* (*)(int,  void (*)(int)))(int)’

Comment: You misunderstood.  What I meant was: `kill` doesn't do what you think it does when its first argument is zero.  (Perhaps you do not realize that you are calling `kill` with first argument zero, in which case read over your code paying close attention to the values `child_a` and `child_b` have in each conditional branch.) Then read [the `kill(2)` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) to learn what it does when its first argument is zero.  But I reiterate that _you don't need to use `kill` in this program_.